# Find an html element which has a class but the class name is varying or unknown

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-selectors, getelementsbyclassname

Find an html element which has a class but the class name is varying or unknown.

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <table class="jasdhuioheurbyiwefnio">
                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

**In the above html only one table has a class(class="jasdhuioheurbyiwefnio") The class name is a dynamically changing. How to Get the table?**

Comment: How about finding a table that has a `class` attribute? Looks like the other table doesn't have one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
table[class]
```

selector "table that has class attribute". But it's not very reliable though, since it can match more tables than you need.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried $("table[class]")?

Answer (score 0):

write one static Id and get the table through the ID.

Comment: its automatically generating html. can't assign static ID